# Method to retrieve category names and IDs only as an array?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm building a category picker select list. I just need to populate an array of categorys like so:

```
$myCats = array("null" => "None (default)", "1" => "Uncategorized", "2" => "Second Category", etc..)
```

Does WP have an existing method call I can use to pull this data alone? I may need to exclude some categories from the listing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)?

```
wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&exclude=1,2,3&selected=6');
```

Comment: this looks like a viable option. I just need to pass a "selected" value as an argument in my script which is already set up to read an array sequence. Thanks!

Comment: You can exclude cats with the 'exclude' parameter passing a list of IDs, and you can pass the selected ID with the 'selected' parameter. I edited to add a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

how about just `get_categories`?

```
$myCats = get_categories( array( 'exclude'=>'1,2' ) );
$myArray = array();
foreach( $myCats as $cat ){
    $myArray[ $cat->cat_ID ] = $cat->name;
}
```